# Visualizar valores de formulario antes de enviar

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buenos días, tengo un form para hacer tests en la que va acumulando las respuestas en un array_keys con las correctas, incorrectas y en blanco. Lo que me gustaría saber es si en el encabezado del form puedo ir visualizando las correctas, incorrectas y en blanco antes de enviar el post.

Las variables las voy acumulando en php así:

```
<div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <span class="orange" style="width: <?php echo $progreso; ?>%;"><span><?php echo round($progreso,0)."%"; ?></span></span>
                        </div>
                        <!--<progress value="<?php echo $i; ?>" max="<?php echo $numero; ?>"></progress> -->
                        <strong><p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p></strong>

                        <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>  
                        <br/>
                        <div id="botones" class="mm-survey-controller">
                            <div class="mm-next-btn">
                                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next' type='button'>Siguiente</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>     

                    <?php }elseif($i<1 || $i<$rows){?>

                    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <span class="orange" style="width: <?php echo $progreso; ?>%;"><span><?php echo round($progreso,0)."%"; ?></span></span>
                        </div> 
                        <strong><p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p></strong>
                        <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>      
                        <br/>
                        <div id="botones" class="mm-survey-controller">
                            <div class="mm-prev-btn">
                                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous' type='button'>Anterior</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mm-next-btn">
                                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next' type='button'>Siguiente</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php }elseif($i==$rows){?>

                    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <span class="orange" style="width: <?php echo $progreso; ?>%;"><span><?php echo round($progreso,0)."%"; ?></span></span>
                        </div> 
                        <strong><p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p></strong>
                        <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
                        <br/>
                        <div id="botones" class="mm-survey-controller">
                            <div class="mm-prev-btn">
                                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous' type='button'>Anterior</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mm-next-btn">
                                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next' type='submit'>Finalizar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } $i++;} ?>
                </form>

if(isset($_POST[1])){ 
    $keys=array_keys($_POST);
    $order=join(",",$keys);

    $response=mysql_query("select id,answer from $bd where id IN($order) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$order)")   or die(mysql_error());
    $right_answer=0;
    $wrong_answer=0;
    $unanswered=0;
    $r = 0;
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){
        if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result['id']]){ 
            $right_answer++;
        }else if($_POST[$result['id']]==5){
            $unanswered++;
        }else{
            $wrong_answer++;
            ${'x'.$r} = $result['id'];
            echo $x[$r];
            $r++; 
        }
    }

    echo "right_answer : ". $right_answer."<br>";
    echo "wrong_answer : ". $wrong_answer."<br>";
    echo "unanswered : ". $unanswered."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Hola Vieira. No está claro lo que pides... has intentado visualizarlas de alguna manera? Qué errores o problemas tuviste en el intento?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código HTML del formulario. Los campos de preguntas son cada uno un conjunto de `<input type="radio">`? ¿El valor de estos inputs va de 1 a 4 siendo 5 el valor por defecto cuando no se elige ninguno? Para saber en el front si la respuesta es correcta o incorrecta tendrías que tener de antemano un objeto con las respuestas correctas como variable en el entorno del browser

Comment: Gracias por contestar @lois6b pues no lo he intentado porque no tengo idea de como poder hacerlo... lo que quisiera visualiazar en el formulario "en tiempo real" serían las variables $right_answer, $wrong_answer y $unanswered conforme voy dándole al boton siguiente (cuando paso de una pregunta a otra)

Comment: Lo más importante es que lo intentes. Si no tienes ideas, has de buscar un poco e investigar. Cuando lo intentes, muestranos qué te detiene o que dificultades exactas y concretas tienes. Si no es muy amplio lo que pides. Un saludo

Comment: @amenadiel ya he puesto el form con los valores que toma el radio... son 4 respuestas por pregunta.

Comment: O sea tu tabla de preguntas y respuestas tiene campos id, answer, question_name, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4 ? Podrías poner los contenidos de la tabla para imaginarme como se renderea el formulario.

Comment: Exacto y otro campo mas con la respuesta correcta, que puede tener valor 1, 2, 3 o 4 según si la respuesta correcta es a) b) c) o d) Cuando toma valor 5 es que la has dejado en blanco.